# haskell counting Even numbers In a list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to put together a recursive function that counts the amount of even elements in a list and so far this is what I have came up with but obviously for those who are experienced in this language will be able to see what the issue is and the error message doesn't come till after I input a list and I have no clue what its referring to, any help would be appreciated

```
evenNumCount  [] = []
evenNumCount  (x:xs)
    | ev == True    = 1 + (evenNumCount xs )
    | otherwise     = evenNumCount xs
    where ev    = even x
```

Comment: (you can replace `| ev == True = 1 + (evenNumCount xs) where ev = even x` with just `| even x = 1 + evenNumCount xs`)

Comment: Also you could do `evenNumCount = length . filter even`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your base case should be:

```
evenNumCount [] = 0
```

If you look at the type of your `evenNumCount` definition in GCHi, it is

```
evenNumCount :: (Integral t, Num [a]) => [t] -> [a]
```

when you want it to be

```
evenNumCount :: (Integral t, Num a) => [t] -> a
```

Comment: @Abstract3000 ....or perhaps even `evenNumCount :: [Int] -> Int`. Always provide type signatures, it helps you match your code with your expectations. In this case, the `1 + (evenNumCount xs)` line would have worked if you could treat lists as numbers, which is why the `Num [a]` constraint was there.

Comment: Sorry to hijack your answer as my soapbox, I was too lazy to write my own. Have an upvote by means of agreement and apology.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was much simpler of a fix than i thought. I'm just barely learning this language and I have been having a rough time with the Type signatures and fully comprehending them, have read that chapter 4X now and slowly grasping it but I guess practice makes perfect, I really appreciate the advice and the help :)